# How is the energy bill split in academic departments?

Tags: lab-management, facilities-services

Consider a physics department for example. Does each lab get metered and pay its own bill in the United States, or does the department itself cover overhead? Do energy leaks get noticed and managed? Do you get yelled at for leaving the lights on?

What's the norm on who foots the energy bill?

Comment: Given some equipment in physics labs  you can leave the lights on for 50 years and it won't be noticed.

Comment: I think this will be closed as specific to the regulations of an institution.  A better question might be: Do grants pay utility bills?

Comment: Years ago one hot July day in New Jersey, I was in the accelerator lab running an experiment. The building folks came on the PA system and said that Con Edison had asked us to cut back on power to help prevent a brown out. The lab owner looked around the lab, stared at the ion accelerator for a bit (perhaps 25kW), and walked over to the door and turned off the room lights. That was our contribution...

Comment: Interesting question, I am curious to know the answer. To me, it feels relevant to academia SE.

Comment: Many grants include a negotiated overhead rate, which covers things like office space and electricity. But I am curious about whether ultra-high-energy equipment like GPU farms and particle accelerators are metered separately.

Comment: @JonCuster I like the cut of your jib.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there are no universal rules or norms. My university changed the system drastically a few years ago and it is very complicated right now

Answer (score 1):

At the institutions where I worked in the US, a fixed overhead from grants, negotiated with the granting agency usually (e.g. X University takes YY% from all NSF grants held at X) went to those kinds of costs. I do not know of any exceptions, but we were more likely to be running refrigeration units and ovens than ion accelerators and each individual institute may have special exceptions. You would have to inquire directly.